# Inheriting from linked classes

Tags: oop

This question is about OOP in any statically typed language.  Suppose I have two classes whose instances maintain pointers/references to each other.  In my case, one class is a container, and the other a wrapper around a contained object which maintains a pointer to the container in which it lives.

```
class Container {
  Element[] elements;
}
class Element {
  // ... data...
  Container holds_me;
}
```

The constructor of `Container` creates an `Element` object to wrap each contained object, and sets their `holds_me` pointers to itself.

Now I want to inherit from these classes.  I want a `DerivedContainer` class, which inherits from `Container` and contains `DerivedElement` objects, where `DerivedElement` inherits from `Element` and refers to the containing `DerivedContainer` object.  What is the right way to do this (or is it the wrong thing to do)?

The most straightforward thing is for the constructor of `DerivedContainer` to create `DerivedElement`s and store them in `elements` and set their `holds_me` pointer to itself.  Then all the methods of `Container` and `Element` will work, but any new methods defined in `DerivedContainer` and `DerivedElement` will have to downcast the objects held in `elements` and `holds_me` in order to invoke any new methods on them that weren't defined in the base classes.  This doesn't seem pretty; so I wonder, is there a better solution?

Comment: Just a suggestion--the double-linked connection you use may end up being problematic.  If your container class had a static lookup method "findContaienrWith(object)" it may reduce some of the complexity you'll run into later.  Also that method can be re-implemented as you add requirements (say you need a case where two containers hold the same object or something similarly nasty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is the right way to do it, without any more information, IMHO. It makes sense if you think that all of the methods in Element can apply to every Element, but the *only* classes that should know anything about the Derived set of functionality are (ideally only) DerivedElement and (if necessary) DerivedContainer. In other words, to anyone else, Elements and Containers are *only* Elements and Containers.

You can sometimes do a little better with templates(C++) or generics(Java), since the thought behind these features is that a `Container<Element>` knows that it holds Elements and a `Container<DerivedElement>` knows that it holds DerivedElements, but if you have a heterogeneous Container, you really have to have each subclass handle the derived functionality by trying to downcast.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I was hoping that the derived classes could somehow ensure statically that their references only point to other derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

If your language supports it, you could use Generics/Templates. The Container class could have the Elements class as a parameterized type. That way, you can forget about downcasting the Elements.

Comment: But then `Container<DerivedElement>` wouldn't be a subclass of `Container<Element>`, would it?

Comment: Yes, but is that really necessary? With the original design, a Container is always a Container, no matter what it holds inside. The Elements it contains can form a class hierarchy or not, and that is still true with the Generics design. I don't see why you would want Container<DerivedElement> to be a subclass of Container<Element>. Is it because of the Liskov principle? (A Container<DerivedElement> must be a Container<Element>, therefore it must be a subclass)

Comment: It's probably not clear from my example.  I didn't intend Container to be a generic container object; in my intended application it's something more specific which _happens_ to also contain a bunch of Elements, and DerivedContainer extends the functionality of Container in ways other than just containing a different sort of element.

Comment: Well, if Container is a more "tailor-made" kind of container, your original solution is not that bad in my eyes now :P

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I've realized that it's possible to do more or less what I originally wanted here using abstract types.  Here is some Scala code:

```
abstract class Container { ctnr =>
  type E <: Element
  class Element { this : E =>
    // data
    def holds_me = ctnr
  }
  var elements : Array[E]
}
```

The original container is an abstract class containing both a nested class of elements and an abstract type of elements.  The subtyping assertion `E <: Element` requires `E` to always be a subclass of `Element`, while the self reference `this : E =>` forces any instantiation of `Element` to belong to the type `E` (as instantiated by some implementation of `Container`).

```
class ContainerImpl extends Container {
  type E = Element
  // initialize 'elements' using 'new Element()'
}

abstract class DerivedContainer extends Container {
  override type E <: DerivedElement
  class DerivedElement extends Element { this : E =>
    // more data
  }
}

class DerivedContainerImpl extends DerivedContainer {
  type E = DerivedElement
  // initialize 'elements' using 'new DerivedElement()'
}
```